# How can the return value of an OCMock stub be changed?

Tags: unit-testing, ocmock

It seems that the first time I add *andReturnValue* on an OCMock stub, that return value is set in stone. For example:

```
id physics = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[DynamicPhysicsComponent class]
Entity *testEntity = [Entity entityWithPhysicsComponent:physics];
CGPoint velocity1 = CGPointMake(100, 100);
CGPoint velocity2 = CGPointZero;
[[[physics stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(velocity1)] getCurrentVelocity];
[testEntity update:0.1];
[[[physics stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(velocity2)] getCurrentVelocity];
[testEntity update:0.1];
```

The stubbed method is called in [testEntity update]. But each time the stubbed method is returning the velocity1 value, so I guess the second attempt to set the methods return value isn't honoured.

Is there a way to do do this in OCMock?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When you `stub` a method, you're saying it should always function in the specified way, no matter how many times it's called. The easiest way to fix this is to change `stub` to `expect`:

```
CGPoint velocity1 = CGPointMake(100, 100);
CGPoint velocity2 = CGPointZero;
[[[physics expect] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(velocity1)] getCurrentVelocity];
[testEntity update:0.1];
[[[physics expect] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(velocity2)] getCurrentVelocity];
[testEntity update:0.1];
```

Alternatively, if you need to `stub` (for example if the method might not be called at all), you can just re-create the mock:

```
CGPoint velocity1 = CGPointMake(100, 100);
CGPoint velocity2 = CGPointZero;
[[[physics stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(velocity1)] getCurrentVelocity];
[testEntity update:0.1];
[physics verify];

physics = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[Physics class]];
[[[physics stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(velocity2)] getCurrentVelocity];
[testEntity update:0.1];
[physics verify];
```

Comment: I see. I wasn't using expect because I had no need for verify, but using it to change the mocked method behaviour (as in your first example) works well for my case. Thanks.

Comment: In your second example, what's the purpose of `verify` when used with a stubbed method?

Comment: I suppose the verify might not be necessary. I was just trying to point out that you'd call verify on the mock (if appropriate to your test, say if there were other expectations) before you assign a new mock to it.

Comment: For anyone who got an error `no known instance method for selector 'expect'` like me, you need to cast your stub to a `OCMockObject *`.

Answer (score 30):

Actually when you `stub` you're only setting the return value in stone if you use `andReturn` or `andReturnValue`. You can use the method `andDo` to change the returned value whenever you want. This is a improvement over `expect` where you need to know how many times a method will get called. Here the code snippet to accomplish this:

```
__weak TestClass *weakSelf = self;
[[[physics stub] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
    NSValue *result = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:weakSelf.currentVelocity];
    [invocation setReturnValue:&result];
}] getCurrentVelocity];
```

Comment: I like this answer better because you're not enforcing how many times the stubbed method must be called (as -expect) would do.

Answer (score 3):

While I think CipherCom has the correct answer I find myself preferring to create a helper class for returning various values.  I've had issues with `NSInvocation` in the past.

```
@interface TestHelper : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint velocity;
- (CGPoint)getCurrentVelocity;
@end

@implementation TestHelper
- (CGPoint)getCurrentVelocity
{
    return self.velocity;
}
@end
```

Then in my test class I'd have a private member variable for `TestHelper` and in `setUp` method I'd do:

```
self.testHelper = [TestHelper new];

[[[physics stub] andCall:@selector(getCurrentVelocity) onObject:self.testHelper]
                 getCurrentVelocity];
```

That way in each of my tests I could set the velocity to what I want for the test.

`self.testHelper.velocity = CGPointMake(100, 200);`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like neither `andReturn`/`andReturnValue`/`andDo` doesn't get overriden when called multiple times. My workaround was to add a property to the test class and use that to control what the mocked object should return. For example in case of an `isAvailable` property on a mocked object, my code would look like:

```
@interface MyTest: XCTestCase 
@property BOOL stubbedIsAvailable;
@end

@implementation MyTest

- (void)setUp {
    [OCMStub([myMockedObject isAvailable]) andDo:^(NSInvocation invocation) {
        BOOL retVal = self.stubbedIsAvailable;
        [invocation setReturnValue:&retVal];
    }
}

- (void)testBehaviourWhenIsAvailable {
    self.stubbedIsAvailable = YES;
    // test the unit
}

- (void)testBehaviourWhenIsNotAvailable {
    self.stubbedIsAvailable = NOT;
    // test the unit
}
```